# Write to a specific position in vector in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have this library function that reads from a socket and writes the content into a vector:

```
writeIntoVector( vector<char>& aVector, int nr_of_bytes  );
```

I am reading data in chunks from the socket and want to place the content read from the socket directly into a vector. Such that the first writeIntoVector writes the data into the vector from position 0, the next call to writeIntoVector writes the data from the socket into the vector at position nr_of_bytes/2 (in the case of a char) and so on. 
I suspect this can be done using pointers but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean `writeIntoVector()`is what you have to use and cannot change? Or is it under your control?

Comment: How exactly is this library function declared? I don't think it's likely to be `writeIntoVector( vector<char> aVector, int nr_of_bytes  );`.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [`std::vector::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Comment: It probably should be `writeIntoVector( vector<char> &aVector, int nr_of_bytes);` (pass vector by reference)

Comment: What does 'and so on' mean? Is the next position `nr_of_bytes` and the one after '(3*nr_of_bytes)/2'? Why write at intervals of half a parameter?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy _"is not suitable for random-index inserting"_ What do you mean?? You can use `insert()` for inserting at any position in the `std::vector`.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking. What is `nr_of_bytes`? The number of bytes read in total? In the most recent socket read? The previous socket read? How does it relate to the size of the vector? Where does the expression `nr_of_bytes/2` come from?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I assume he was referring to the fact that inserting anywhere except the end is not O(1), but for `vector<char>` the resulting `memcpy` calls are not going to matter much unless the vector gets large.

Comment: @JonathanWakely you got me right. Also, I doubt TurboWhale will have a small vector because of placing there the data of socket read.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `writeIntoVector()` is your own function, you could try something like this, using **indices**:

```
size_t writeIntoVector(const size_t startPos, std::vector<char> & out)
{
  // write from startPos to at most out.size() - 1
  // return number of written elements
}
```

An **iterator**-based approach could look like this:

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator Iter;

Iter writeIntoRange(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
  // write from begin to at most end - 1
  // return last iterator, that was actually modified
}
```

Comment: Plus 1 (ffs) for the iterator approach. That's how it should work in C++.

Comment: I can't retract my vote now, but the iterator approach looks questionable, you need to resize the vector first, or use `back_insert_iterator`, so seems error prone as written. Making `writeIntoRange` a function seems to have no advantage over a simple `memcpy` into the vector's data (reads from a socket are unlikely to be done a single byte at a time).

Comment: @JonathanWakely The question is too broad to provide a solution that's safe for every situation. Reading data from a socket and writing it into a fixed-size buffer is not uncommon, I believe. Automatically increasing the container size, depending on what's read from the socket could also be problematic because one could run out of memory.

Comment: Agreed, I'm just not sure `writeToRange` actually helps solve any part of the problem. If you prefer a range-like API, why restrict it to only working with `vector<char>::iterator` when `char*` would be more flexible and support other types of fixed-length buffer? (obtained from a vector with `vector::data()`). If `writeToRange` reads 128 bytes from the socket and `distance(begin, end) == 100` what does it do with the extra bytes? In most case it would be better to try and resize the vector, and throw `bad_alloc` if it can't, rather than return `end` with no indication that 28 bytes were lost.

Comment: I understand your objections but I also doubt the OP could make much use of an answer that goes into all these details. I meant to roughly and quickly show the concepts that could be applied. I didn't mean to put a lot of effort into a solution that *maybe* could be useful for the OP's situation.  The question is just too broad.